# How to handle multiple sessions in passport js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using passport js for authenticating a request, however in my application I need to maintain two different types of session, one for admin user and one for normal user so that if an admin logs in then the session should be maintained and if a user logs in then the session should be mainatined seperately, right now I am using two passport strategies that is one for user and the other for admin_user but the session that I am getting from req.session.passport.user is the one who logs in last, is there any way to make it seperate something like req.session.passport.admin and req.session.passport.user ? right now the strategies that I have looks like below.

```
     passport.use('admin', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
      },
      function(email, password, done) {
        var adminflag = 'admin';
        db.adminUser.find({ where: { email: email }}).success(function(user) {
          if (!user) {
            done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user' });
          } else if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
            done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password'});
          } else {
            console.log('Login (local) : { id: ' + user.id + ', username: ' + user.username + ' }');
            done(null, user);
          }
        }).error(function(err){

          done(err);
        });
      }
    ));

passport.use('user', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(email, password, done) {
    var userflag = 'user';
    db.User.find({ where: { email: email }}).success(function(user) {
      if (!user) {
        done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user' });
      } else if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
        done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password'});
      } else {
        console.log('Login (local) : { id: ' + user.id + ', username: ' + user.username + ' }');
        done(null, user);
      }
    }).error(function(err){
      done(err);
    });
  }
));
```

Comment: Why can't you have one user db where each user have a property isAdmin with value either true or false?

Comment: @Molda This is my requirement however if I do that how will I be able to maintain two sessions(one for user and one for admin) on the basis of that key?

Comment: Not sure what you trying to achieve. Admin is just a user with higher privileges. Say you want to render a delete button to admins only so just check if user.isAdmin than render it. If you want only admin to enter admin section do the same check user.isAdmin . i can't se need for another session